# how to replace a value in yaml file

Tags: bash, sed, yaml, salt-stack

The yaml file is like this:

```
settings:
  clusterName: dev
  dbServer: test.db.com
  dcsHostName: dev
  overrideDevRepo: "true"
  globalSuspend: "true"
  sharedConfig: "true"
```

I want to pass globalSuspend as a toggle variable, update true to false or false to true, but as helm need the quote, so quote are needed, also yaml is format sensitive, the leading spaces must be kept as same.  Need a way to do it saltstack simple cmd.run or state playbook. Or at least please help on how to do in bash.  But I find my command works in bash does not work in saltstack as : colon is a trouble in salt.  thanks.

```
"toggle the suspend value":
  cmd.run:
    - name: sed -i  '/globalSuspend/!b;c \ \ globalSuspend: "{{suspend}}"' settings.yaml
    - runas: vagrant
```

The above does not work because of the colon and also does not keep the leading spaces.

Comment: Consider using [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

Comment: ...or python if you can't install [tag:yq].

Comment: You could consider using Saltstack to render complete templates for Helm. Helm should mostly support booleans such as `true/false` though.

Answer (score 0):

Colon is a special character in YAML. Use a literal block scalar to treat everything as content:

```yaml
"toggle the suspend value":
  cmd.run:
    - name: |-
        sed -i  '/globalSuspend/!b;c \ \ globalSuspend: "{{suspend}}"' settings.yaml
    - runas: vagrant
```

`|` starts a literal block scalar. Each following line that is more indented is part of the scalar. The `-` means that the final line break is not part of the scalar (wich it would otherwise be).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with a [`file.serialize`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.serialize) state.

```yaml
toggle the suspend value:
  file.serialize:
    - name: settings.yaml
    - dataset:
        settings:
          globalSuspend: "{{ suspend }}"
    - serializer: yaml
    - merge_if_exists: true
```

More specific states are always preferred to a generic `cmd.run`, as they are state-aware and more efficient to run.